# Attach watermark image in each page of PDF

Tags: java, pdf, grails, groovy, pdf-generation

In my grails project I am using grails rendering plug-in to convert a GSP into PDF. PDF have 3 to 5 pages.

Now I need to attach a watermark as bottom right of each page of the PDF.

I have no idea how can I achieve this. Any help highly appreciated.

**EDIT..............**

My gsp which is used to generate pdf is a template.

I am using grails 2.2.0 and plugins.rendering=0.4.3.

Below is my code..,.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<style type="text/css">
    @page {
        size: 210mm 297mm;
        @bottom-right {content: element(footer)}
    }
</style>
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
...
</table>
```

Comment: As your question is tagged `java,` would a pure Java solution help? Furthermore, what do you want to watermark with? An image? Some text? Some page of another PDF? In the latter case, a Java solution making use of the [iText](http://itextpdf.com) library is shown in the example [StampStationery](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=119).

Comment: Grails support Java and hence pure Java is also acceptable but please keep in mind that I am using rendering plug-in to generate PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the rendering plugin you have access to [flying saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) and its support für `@page` rules.

With this you could define [running elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-css3-gcpm-20070504/#running1) as defined in the CSS 3 specification.

So you could define a footer element within your gsp:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="footer">Your Watermark</div>
    ...
</body>
```

And style it like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @page {
        size: 210mm 297mm;
        @bottom-right {content: element(footer)};
        ...
    }

    #footer{
        position: running(footer);
    }

    ...
</style>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is giving me the error

"ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SAXParseException occurred when processing request: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    Line | Method
->> 1231 | parse in com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser"

Comment: Did you already rendered a pdf successfully (without watermark)? The error message says that you have a not well-formed xml file. So check your gsp to guarantee a well-formed xml output.

Comment: Yes without above given style pdf is generated successfully.

Comment: The @page property works for me in my grails 2.1.0 app using plugins.rendering=0.4.3. Please try it with a very basic version and show us the code if this version is not working.

Comment: I am using grails 2.2.0 and plugins.rendering=0.4.3. 
May be my syntax is wrong.
Please see my edited question.

Comment: Is this your whole file? I would add the default html structure: html, head, body! Try to implement a very basic example to find out what is causing the SAXParseException ...

Comment: I am converting template to pdf. Yes above is my whole file with some dynamic content in the table. The template is also rendered in some gsp view to show document in the browser as well and hence I cannot add head, body in the template.

Comment: Try to add a new view with a correct structure, include your template and use this to generate your pdf.

Comment: Yes you are right, with head body it works but with little modification.
<div style="position: running(footer); text-align: right">Your Watermark</div>

Comment: Please try it and if it runs then modify your answer so that I can accept it. Thanks..,.

Comment: Ahhh - I forgot the position part of the footer div - sorry!

Comment: For the love of everything don't make the same mistake I did - you must use <!DOCTYPE html>.  If you use anything else, even an xhtml declaration, it won't work!!